# Where can you find http timings in the glimpse popup window?

Tags: glimpse

The Glimpse javascript panel shows a nice summary of http timing information. The time spent on the wire, the time on the server, etc....

[image: Glimpse Javascript window]

However when you view the information using the pop out, that information is no longer accessible. I can't find http timings anywhere. Is there anyway to view this information without viewing it directly through the javascript injected panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this point, the answer is no.

There has been [some community work](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/pull/192) to bring the full data set available from [the navigation timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) into Glimpse.

That effort is a bit stale now, but if you'd like to pick it back up you'd be able to get not only http timings, but all of the following:

- navigationStart
- unloadEventStart
- unloadEventEnd
- redirectStart
- redirectEnd
- fetchStart
- domainLookupStart
- domainLookupEnd
- connectStart
- connectEnd
- secureConnectionStart
- requestStart
- responseStart
- responseEnd
- domLoading
- domInteractive
- domContentLoadedEventStart
- domContentLoadedEventEnd
- domComplete
- loadEventStart
- loadEventEnd

AND [it would work in almost all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing) (excluding oldIE).