# How can I troubleshoot long Glimpse wire times in an ASP.NET Web site?

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

I'm using [Glimpse](http://getGlimpse.com) v1.6.1 to troubleshoot performance problems on an ASP.NET Web site.  The Glimpse heads-up display breaks down the request time into three categories: wire, server, and client.  I'm seeing cases where the wire time is quite high (20 seconds), particularly on initial page loads.  What is the best way to drill into the wire time to find the bottleneck?  I suspect that the ASP.NET JIT compilation time is being included in the wire time instead of the server time, but I'm not sure.

There are a couple of related questions already on StackOverflow with very helpful answers, but neither seemed to have exactly the answer that I'm looking for:

- [Where can you find http timings in the glimpse popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492058/where-can-you-find-http-timings-in-the-glimpse-popup-window)
- [How does Glimpse calculate the timings for server, wire and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640408/how-does-glimpse-calculate-the-timings-for-server-wire-and-client)

Comment: I'm having very high Client time when I use Glimpse with Visual-Studio Development Server. Hosting in IIS server seems avoiding this issue. But I like to know how Wire, Server, and CLient time are calculated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a redirect. Glimpse includes the time used for any redirects into the "Wire" time. "Server" time refers only to the destination page, after any redirects.